# Design XSLT to create a comma separated value list

Tags: xslt

I am not a code developer, my tool has a restriction in this case with the default XSLT.  I have tried editing the default XSLT and creating a new one, but i am not getting the desired output. So, I want to write a custom XSLT and I need your help on that.

I have tried applying template and `xsl:value-of select="/Records/Record/Record/Record/Field[@id='23425']" separator=", "/>`, but it's not working.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Record contentId="490422" levelId="49" levelGuid="efcc872e-8014-4d1f-8830-6a63d0bd51d9" moduleId="71" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="490431" levelId="397" levelGuid="9a560130-79ad-4250-9901-3eafc4e0e799" moduleId="600" parentId="0">
            <Record contentId="490425" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Program 1</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user1</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490425</Field>
            </Record>
            <Record contentId="490426" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Program 2</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user2</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490426</Field>
            </Record>
            <Field id="23429" guid="2bc40ece-8e0e-4f11-9e67-7d15e4021746" type="1">SErvice 4</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="120" guid="bd1c1f0e-47df-4a21-bbd7-473557d8a278" type="1">Device 1</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="490423" levelId="49" levelGuid="efcc872e-8014-4d1f-8830-6a63d0bd51d9" moduleId="71" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="490432" levelId="397" levelGuid="9a560130-79ad-4250-9901-3eafc4e0e799" moduleId="600" parentId="0">
            <Record contentId="490427" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Copy of Program 1</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user5</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490427</Field>
            </Record>
            <Record contentId="490428" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Copy of Program 2</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user4</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490428</Field>
            </Record>
            <Record contentId="490429" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Copy of Program 3</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user5</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490429</Field>
            </Record>
            <Field id="23429" guid="2bc40ece-8e0e-4f11-9e67-7d15e4021746" type="1">Service 2</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="490431" levelId="397" levelGuid="9a560130-79ad-4250-9901-3eafc4e0e799" moduleId="600" parentId="0">
            <Record contentId="490425" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Program 1</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user1</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490425</Field>
            </Record>
            <Record contentId="490426" levelId="398" levelGuid="2ef4fb6a-092e-471e-b481-1a6380022e10" moduleId="601" parentId="0">
                <Field id="23426" guid="dd028a89-90de-4ca0-9d08-c9d2d0c47a19" type="1">Program 2</Field>
                <Field id="23425" guid="0b389b7f-efc3-4933-92c3-0388e0ceb4e7" type="1">user2</Field>
                <Field id="23422" guid="83c5d064-5c90-45f7-a2c7-635b42a69bdd" type="6">490426</Field>
            </Record>
            <Field id="23429" guid="2bc40ece-8e0e-4f11-9e67-7d15e4021746" type="1">SErvice 4</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="120" guid="bd1c1f0e-47df-4a21-bbd7-473557d8a278" type="1">Device 2</Field>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Needed Output/Transformed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArcherRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
   <ArcherRecord>
      <Device_Name>Device 1</Device_Name>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490425</Field_id>
      </Programs>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490426</Field_id>
      </Programs>
   <ProgExecutive>user 1,user 2<ProgExecutive>
   </ArcherRecord>
   <ArcherRecord>
      <Device_Name>Device 2</Device_Name>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490425</Field_id>
      </Programs>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490426</Field_id>
      </Programs>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490427</Field_id>
      </Programs>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490428</Field_id>
      </Programs>
      <Programs>
         <Field_id>490429</Field_id>
      </Programs>
   <ProgExecutive>user 3,user 4,user 5, user 1, user 2<ProgExecutive>
   </ArcherRecord>
</ArcherRecords>
```

Comment: First, we're here to answer your questions, we're not here to write your code for you, nor to give you personal tutorials and training. Second, we can help you find what's wrong with your code, but for that you need to show us enough code for us to reproduce the problem. Finally, if you're using the `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of`, do check that your XSLT processor actually supports XSLT 2.0 or later - many XSLT processors don't.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I had multiple draft XSLTs and all working differently, thats why posting nothing.  Anyway, i have built my own XSLT and made it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Below XSLT is working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Records">
        <ArcherRecords >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record" />
        </ArcherRecords>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record[@levelId='49']">
        <ArcherRecord>
            <xsl:element name="Device_Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='120']" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="Calc_Prog_Executive">
                <xsl:for-each select="Record/Record/Field[@id='23425']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
            <Programs>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/Record" />
            </Programs>
        </ArcherRecord>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record/Record/Record">
        <Tracking_Id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@contentId" />
        </Tracking_Id>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```